# How to edit httpd.conf file in AMAZON EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I am new on AMAZON EC2 Server, recently I have Installed PHP and MySQL and now I want to update file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

but the problem is, when I am going to update it, it display error like - `Permission denied`. What is the best way to update it?

Comment: Did you sudo your edit command?

Comment: yah, but it display error

Comment: @adamdunson its Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09.1 64bit

Comment: The documentation will tell you how you can gain root access your your Amazon Linux AMI; probably you just need to do `sudo -s`.

Comment: @Repox, thanks but `sudo -s` is not working

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: same error `Permission denied`

Comment: @SumitBijvani According to the documentation, the ec2-user has sudo rights. You should be able to use sudo - otherwise it's a support case; not a technical difficulty.

Comment: What about `su` by itself?

Comment: @Repox but I have installed PHP using ec2-user, so I think i have all the rights of editing and deleting files!

Comment: I didn't get you @adamdunson

Comment: I have found solution and its working `$ sudo chown ec2-user /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` thank you all

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You have to change the file as root user. Do this:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Make your changes and save with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Done.

Comment: Don't forget to "sudo /sbin/service httpd restart" it for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @MikeL when I ran this i got `Failed to restart httpd.service: Unit not found.`?!

Answer (score 7):

I have found solution and its working...

`$ sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: or you can just sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: It's not a very good practice to take ownership of a system-wide configuration file whenever you need to modify it. I'm curious as to why you couldn't get `sudo` working before to edit the file. What command were you trying to use?

Comment: This answer proves that sudo works - OP just doesn't know what he's doing. This answer is a terrible solution (as @adamdunson also points out). Changes like these are reasons why sudo and su is introduced.

Comment: Agreed with adamdunson and Repox.  ashpriom's answer is correct, this one is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

It would be prompting you a alert, that you can duplicate it. So

- So duplicate it, store it on desktop with same name
- Edit it for your use(remove comment '#')
- Save it
- Now replace the original file with this one
- it'll prompt for your password, provide that

Now all updates you did are saved in *httpd.conf*
Cheers