# htaccess works in localhost but doesn't work in EC2 instance

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My htaccess file works on localhost but doesn't work when i deploy it to EC2 instance.

I'm using Macbook and in finder i cannot see the htaccess file, i thought that perhaps it didn't get copied to EC2 instance but i don't think this is the problem because when i copy the project i can see the htaccess file in my editor.

Is there something enabling mod rewrite in EC2 linux instance? If there is, i didn't do it or it enables mod rewrite as default?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: FYI – you can show invisible files in OS X by running this Terminal command and restarting Finder. `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.`

Answer (score 70):

I pieced together some info from various posts so I thought I'd put up an answer.

1. As Paul commented, If you're running Amazon EC2 Linux, you're probably running httpd instead of Apache. The file is therefore in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
2. You have to change the file as root user. (from ssh access) Do this: `sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` ([How to edit httpd.conf file in AMAZON EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112424/how-to-edit-httpd-conf-file-in-amazon-ec2))
3. `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"` was listed in two places for me. I had to change the subsequent `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in those two places.
4. Restart apache. I restarted my whole ec2 instance (i have apache configured to start automatically) although just restarting apache should work. But I see the change is working.

I was trying to make the same changes in a .htaccess file (removing the index.php from urls in a code igniter application). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. For others: **Restarting EC2 instance from AWS is a must**.

Comment: You don't need to restart the whole instance, just restart httpd. You can do so via the Command line with /sbin/service httpd restart

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Here we are 5 years after this answer was made.  And people like me are still finding it as the solution.  Makes you wonder why this information is so difficult to find.

Comment: Really helpful, But restarting httpd is must, to do so `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However, every time I deploy a new version, I have to do these steps because it overrides my changes. Does anyone know a way to persist them? And in my file, 'DocumentRoot` was not present. I had to add it myself. I am using AWS Beanstalk CLI to deploy new versions.

Comment: Spot on solution. worked like a charm (01.2023).

Answer (score 8):

By default EC2 doesn't have .htaccess enabled, you must edit your httpd.config to allow for it.

In /etc/apache/sites-available/default change AllowOverRide = None to AllowOverRide = All.

Comment: Yes they are hidden but when i copy the folder hidden files are missed? So, i'm trying to understand that the problem is that i cannot copy my .htaccess file to server.

Comment: Have you tried simply copying the contents of the .htaccess to .htaccess on the remote server?

Comment: I'm using Amazon EC2 Linux instance and i dont know how to do it. Is there a different .htaccess file in server besides i copied?

Comment: If you're running Amazon EC2 Linux, you're probably running httpd instead of Apache. The file is therefore in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` - be sure to amend both `<Directory "/var/www">` and `<Directory "/var/www/html">` as appropriate

Answer (score 3):

Its a three step process

1. Configure apache mod_rewrite,run in terminal.
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. add the following code to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

> ```
> DocumentRoot /var/www
> <Directory />
> Options FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> <Directory /var/www/>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> AllowOverride All
> Order allow,deny
> allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

3.Restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are three steps**

1. Configure apache mod_rewrite,run in terminal. sudo a2enmod rewrite
2. Add this code in this file after closing VirtualHost tag /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

   DocumentRoot /var/www

   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All


   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
3. Restart apache server by command

   sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

When you using the apache2 server

Go to the following directory.

**cd /etc/apache2/sites-available**

If you use LS command here you will see the following file.

**000-default.conf**

That's the file with default apache configuration which are applied to your sites in /var/www/html folder.

Open this file for editing.

**sudo nano 000-default.conf**

Add following lines after DocumentRoot /var/www/html line.

```
Options FollowSymLinks AllowOverride All Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews AllowOverride All Order allow,deny allow from all
```

Save the file and restart the apache.

**sudo service apache2 restart**

that's it and now your .htaccess file will work

Comment: This caused the apache to crash.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux enviroment
1 - cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

2 - sudo nano 000-default.conf

and paste this code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This worked on AWS instance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am not running httpd, but only Apache.

I followed [this website](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/url-rewriting-in-apache) and it works.

Step 1: Enable mod_rewrite module in Apache

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`
Then restart the Apache HTTP server with service command with sudo:

`sudo service apache2 restart`
or using the systemctl command with sudo:

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`
Now that we have mod_rewrite enabled, we can proceed further to configure it.

Step 2: Enable the usage of the .htaccess file

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Find the following section in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. You should see the code like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change, from AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hi your answer may address or not the question, but code formatting is a great way to make others quickly understand what you typed. Please format your code using the visual editor or markdown syntax. Docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)