# Mod Rewrite EC2

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I have followed instructions in another SO post to enable `mod_rewrite` on EC2. I have this setup:

```
# Configure /var/www/html
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?jobs$ jobs.html [L]
```

However when I visit http://example.com/jobs it fails to rewrite. I have checked with phpinfo() and mod_rewrite is enabled in PHP. What else could be preventing rewrite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408349/htaccess-works-in-localhost-but-doesnt-work-in-ec2-instance this link will help you

Comment: yep been following those instructions, which has got me to the point above, but the rewrites arent functioning

Comment: Move Your .htaccess to Your project folder. And try..